# kivy:carousel inside scrollview swipe event becomes hard

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I am new to kivy, I have an app that contains a scrollview ,that contains a stacklayout that will be filled with carousels, the problem is that it becomes to hard to swipe the carousels.
note that when I remove the scrollview the swiping works good
it is giving me hard time please tell me what to do

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I learned from some websites that this has a relation with events order of dispatching, if i could make the scrollview ignor the sliding event and pass it directly to its children, but i don't know how

Comment: The `ScrollView` has `do_scroll_x` and `do_scroll_y` properties, and the `Carousel` has `direction` and `ignore_perpendicular_swipes` properties. Have you tried setting those properties to avoid having both classes trying to use the same swipe event?

Comment: Yes Jhon i tried to set do_scroll_x value to False and ignore_perpendicular_swipes to False but always the same problem